# How to disable iphone camera in another ViewControllers (Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, avfoundation

I am building an application that uses the iphone camera using Avfoundation.
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwv4u.jpg)
When I use the camera and then switch viewcontroller, the camera remains on.
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdvUV.jpg)
[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRwiG.jpg)
How can I turn the camera off in other viewcontrollers or just leave the camera on in the viewcontroller itself.

Thank you for your help! I'm grateful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a few minutes to take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: "How can I turn the camera off in other viewcontrollers"  You are saying each view controller is equipped with its own face-time camera or something?

Comment: No, only a viewcontroller has access to the camera, but it remains on even when it's not in that viewcontroller

Comment: @Rogério  Stop the AVCaptureSession in `viewWillDisappear`.

Comment: @RTXGamer Thanks, it worked!